# Accessing generic object in generic list in C#

Tags: c#, list, generics

I am relatively new to C# and I would like to create a list of generic objects.

Here is how I try to do it:

I create a base class:

```
public class BaseClass
{
}
```

And I inherit a generic class from the base class:

```
public class GenericClass<T> : BaseClass where T: struct
{
    public T data;
    public GenericClass(T value)
    {
        data = value;
    }
    public T doSomething()
    {
        return (T)(data * (dynamic)0.826f);
    }
}
```

Then I can create a list of base class:

```
List<BaseClass> ListOfGenericClasses = new List<BaseClass>();
```

And I can add instances of the inherited geneic class:

```
ListOfGenericClasses.Add(new GenericClass<int>(100));            
ListOfGenericClasses.Add(new GenericClass<byte>(101));
ListOfGenericClasses.Add(new GenericClass<float>(10.1f));
ListOfGenericClasses.Add(new GenericClass<double>(100.10));
ListOfGenericClasses.Add(new GenericClass<ulong>(9999999999));
ListOfGenericClasses.Add(new GenericClass<long>(-9999999999));
ListOfGenericClasses.Add(new GenericClass<uint>(62389));
ListOfGenericClasses.Add(new GenericClass<sbyte>(-103));
```

I also can invoke each objects method:

```
string s = "";
s += ((GenericClass<int>)(ListOfGenericClasses[0])).doSomething() + " # ";
s += ((GenericClass<byte>)(ListOfGenericClasses[1])).doSomething() + " # ";
s += ((GenericClass<float>)(ListOfGenericClasses[2])).doSomething() + " # ";
s += ((GenericClass<double>)(ListOfGenericClasses[3])).doSomething() + " # ";
s += ((GenericClass<ulong>)(ListOfGenericClasses[4])).doSomething() + " # ";
s += ((GenericClass<long>)(ListOfGenericClasses[5])).doSomething() + " # ";
s += ((GenericClass<uint>)(ListOfGenericClasses[6])).doSomething() + " # ";
s += ((GenericClass<sbyte>)(ListOfGenericClasses[7])).doSomething();
MessageBox.Show(s);
```

And here comes the question: how do I get the value of each instance in the list generally?

I try to do something like this:

```
string s = "";
for (int i = 0; i < ListOfGenericClasses.Count; i++)
{
    s += ((GenericClass<ListOfGenericClasses[i].GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0]>)(ListOfGenericClasses[i])).dosdoSomething() + " # ";               
}
MessageBox.Show(s);
```

I have the following error message: "Using the generic type 'GenericClass requires 1 type argument'"

EDIT: sorry guys I could have been more precize when asking my question: my point was not to use the return value to build a string it was just for seeing the result on screen

Any help is much apreciated,

Thanks in advance

Comment: In this case, I'd probably have a `public virtual string DoSomethingString() { return null; }` inside `BaseClass` and a `public override string DoSomethingString() { return doSomething().ToString(); }` inside `GenericClass`.

Comment: What would you like to do with that value? You need it as string or?

Comment: BTW, adding strings together like that can get very slow as the list get's bigger, because there will be a new string object created each time. Either work with a `StringBuilder`, or if you follow my suggestion, you can do something like `string s = string.Join(" # ", ListOfGenericClasses.Select(item => item.DoSomethingString());`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this do what you want?

```
string s = "";
for (int i = 0; i < ListOfGenericClasses.Count; i++)
{
    Type type = ListOfGenericClasses[i].GetType();          
    dynamic d = Convert.ChangeType(ListOfGenericClasses[i], type);
    s += d.doSomething() + " # ";               
}
```

It looks like you are trying to implement a union type. I am sure there must be better ways than this.

Answer (score 4):

I'd approach it in a slightly different way:

```
public class BaseClass
{
     public virtual string DoSomethingToString() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

Then you'd implement your derived class as follows:

```
public class GenericClass<T> : BaseClass where T: struct
{
    public T data;
    public GenericClass(T value)
    {
        data = value;
    }

    public T DoSomething()
    {
        return (T)(data * (dynamic)0.826f);
    }

    public override string DoSomethingToString()
    {
        return DoSomething().ToString();
    }
}
```

Now you can iterate `List<BaseClass>` and directly call each element's `DoSomethingToString()` method.

Comment: I think this is the cleanest approach +1

Comment: Might want to give your virtual method a return type :)

Answer (score 0):

Should you use Generics? I re-wrote your app and solved the problem by removing Generics

```
public class GenericClass : BaseClass
{
    public object data;
    public GenericClass(object value)
    {
        this.data = value;
    }
    public object doSomething()
    {
        return (object)(this.data * (dynamic)0.826f);
    }
}
```

Then I did it:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ListOfGenericClasses.Count; i++)
{
    s += ListOfGenericClasses[i].doSomething() + " # ";
}
```

Comment: True, you can do this, but if you care about boxing (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/yz2be5wk.aspx), then it's not the optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use reflection to get the `type` and then from that get the method which you can then invoke:

```
string s = "";
for (int i = 0; i < ListOfGenericClasses.Count; i++)
{
    s += ListOfGenericClasses[i].GetType()
                       .GetMethod("doSomething")
                       .Invoke(ListOfGenericClasses[i], null);
}
```

However, I would recommend you take the approach as suggested by @corak in the comments and by @InBetween in their answer and create a virtual method in `BaseClass` and override it in `GenericClass`.

Comment: Your solution works as well I just cant accept more than one sorry

Answer (score 0):

First use stringBuilder to concat strings, you can cast your object to dynamic to invoke the method you need dynamically:

```
 var stringbuilder = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var l in ListOfGenericClasses)
            {
                var st = (l as dynamic).doSomething() + " # ";
                stringbuilder.Append(st);
            }

    MessageBox.Show(stringbuilder.ToString());
```

Comment: Your solution works as well I just cant accept more than one sorry